# Why ChangeNotifierProvider disappears from Widget Tree when using routes?

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, flutter-navigation

I'm having trouble understanding this: When the `ChangeNotifierProvider` widget is below the `MaterialApp` one in the widget tree, it disappear from the widget tree when I use the `Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement` method to go to the next screen. However, when the `ChangeNotifierProvider` widget is above the `MaterialApp` one in the widget tree, it stays in the widget tree.

Here is a simple example below.

`ChangeNotifierProvider` widget that disappear example:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp( <= DIFFERENCE HERE
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        home: ChangeNotifierProvider(
            create: (context) => ToiletsListModel(), child: SplashWidget()));
  }
}

class SplashWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  SplashWidget();

  @override
  State<SplashWidget> createState() => SplashWidgetState();
}

class SplashWidgetState extends State<SplashWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ElevatedButton(
        child: Text("press"),
        onPressed: goNext,
      ),
    );
  }

  goNext() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3));
    if (mounted) {
      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => HomeScreen()));
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].forEach((t) {
      Provider.of<MyModel>(context, listen: false).mylist.add(t);
    });
    print(Provider.of<MyModel>(context, listen: false).mylist);
  }
}
```

The widget tree:

[image: widget tree 1]

`ChangeNotifierProvider` widget that stays example:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider( <= DIFFERENCE HERE
        create: (context) => ToiletsListModel(),
        child: MaterialApp(title: 'Flutter Demo', home: SplashWidget()));
  }
}

class SplashWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  SplashWidget();

  @override
  State<SplashWidget> createState() => SplashWidgetState();
}

class SplashWidgetState extends State<SplashWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ElevatedButton(
        child: Text("press"),
        onPressed: goNext,
      ),
    );
  }

  goNext() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3));
    if (mounted) {
      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => HomeScreen()));
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].forEach((t) {
      Provider.of<MyModel>(context, listen: false).mylist.add(t);
    });
    print(Provider.of<MyModel>(context, listen: false).mylist);
  }
}
```

The widget tree:

[image: widget tree 2]

It makes me crazy and I can't find any answer. I suppose that `pushReplacement()` does something to the widget tree or that `ChangeNotifierProvider` is not persistent (altough I did not see that in the documentation, i'm not even sure it's possible tbh). Also, I read that using the `ChangeNotifierProvider` above the `MaterialApp` wasn't a good idea but I don't know why.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's about Navigator. MaterialApp creates Navigator under it. When you navigate to a new page, you are creating a new separate branch in widget tree

Comment: Is there a way to create a branch under the `ChangeNotifierProvider` ? I saw something with Custom Navigators but it seems complicated. Also, is it okay to wrap the `MaterialApp` widget inside the `ChangeNotifierProvider` in terms of performance, logic or something else ?

Comment: If you want to provide some changenotifier to the whole app, putting ChangeNotifierProvider above MaterialApp is what you need and absolutely ok

Comment: Okay great, thank you.